# If $\int_Xfd\mu < \infty$ and $\int_X f^{-1}d\mu < \infty$ then $\mu(X) < \infty$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measurable space that has a function $f: X \rightarrow [0, +\infty]$ such that $$\int_Xfd\mu < \infty $$ and $$\int_Xf^{-1}d\mu < \infty $$Show that $\mu(X) < \infty$.

In order to show this, I decided to use the Holder's inequality. Let $p,q \in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$

Then we have $$\int_X|f \times f^{-1}|d\mu \leq (\int_X f^pd\mu)^{\frac{1}{p}}(\int_X (f^{-1})^{q}d\mu)^{\frac{1}{q}}< \infty$$

As $$\int_X|f \times f^{-1}|d\mu = \int_Xd\mu = \mu(X)$$ we thus have $\mu(X) < \infty$

Is my reasoning correct? I am not too used to the usage of Holder's inequality in measurable spaces.

Comment: Why do you think that $\int f^p \, d\mu < \infty$ and $\int (f^{-1})^q \ d\mu < \infty$...? This is, in general, wrong.

Comment: Another approach (besides the answer by saz below) would be to notice by Cauchy-Schwarz that $$\mu(X) = \int_X f^{1/2}f^{-1/2} d\mu \leq \bigg(\int_X f d\mu \bigg)^{1/2} \bigg( \int_X f^{-1} d\mu \bigg)^{1/2} <\infty$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$y + \frac{1}{y} \geq 1 \qquad \text{for all $y \geq 0$}$$

and so

$$f(x)+ \frac{1}{f(x)} \geq 1 \qquad \text{for all $x \in X$}.$$ Integrate both sides...

Comment: Nice, but I think that's more than a hint.

Comment: @zhw. Yeah... better now?

Comment: Yes I think it is. $\,\,$

Comment: In fact, $y + y^{-1} \geqslant 2$ for all $y \geqslant 0$!